# How does iphone application life cycle works in terms of development?

Tags: iphone

Here's what I understand in terms of high level view.

1. user Launches Application
2. Load MainWindow.xib
3. UIApplication Initialized
4. Waiting for events
5. Execute Events
6. Exit Application

My questions is where do **info.plist**, **main.m**,**AppDelegate** and **ViewController.xib** files fit in the above sequence or get called in terms of sequence?

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*User launches application* means that `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` in main.m is invoked.

Everything else happens as a result of that main method, particularly the call to UIApplicationMain.

From the [UIApplicationMain docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html)

> This function instantiates the
>   application object from the principal
>   class and and instantiates the
>   delegate (if any) from the given class
>   and sets the delegate for the
>   application. It also sets up the main
>   event loop, including the
>   application’s run loop, and begins
>   processing events. If the
>   application’s Info.plist file
>   specifies a main nib file to be
>   loaded, by including the NSMainNibFile
>   key and a valid nib file name for the
>   value, this function loads that nib
>   file.

It's all explained there.